# Repair FoxPro Database - recommended tools?

Tags: foxpro

I know zilch about FoxPro, but we're using a product that has a FoxPro DB that we suspect has errors in it. Any recommended tools for analyzing/repairing? Someone mentioned DBFDoctor.

Suggestions sought.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of errors?  What are the symptoms you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use fast and easy-to-use dbf repair tool from http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-recovery/

Answer (score 1):

We use a product called FoxFix by Xitech and it works well for index and memo file issues along with fixing tables that go over the 2GB file size limit.  - http://www.xitech-europe.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is the definitive source on all the repair tools for DBFs:

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~TableCorruptionRepairTools~VFP

Rick Schummer, VFP MVP

Answer (score 0):

Another product is ReFox, and I think might still be available at http://www.hallogram.com/ and has to its right side of "TOP SELLER" products, FoxFix and ReFox.

Comment: Yeah, but that's why I listed FoxFix first....  However, if he has other problems with source code, ReFox is ALSO a tool around FoxPro.... Thanks for the downvote

Comment: Xitech's ReFox is a decompiler, but it contains FoxFix - a great foxpro database recovery utility. It was top dbf recovery tool for the last 20 years

Answer (score 0):

What problems are you having, and do you have access to a copy of Foxpro? Often what happens with Foxpro tables is that the index files go out of sync with the data files, and then records disappear and reappear depending on which (if any) is the active index. These type of problems can be fixed with a little bit of Foxpro code and exclusive access of the database and don't require third party tools.